# Pythonanywhere Setup

Tags: python, security, passwords, pythonanywhere

I have created a python bot that will log in to an online store, and send an email with all the items on sale in a favorite list. It will be updated whenever there is a change in # of sale items. I don't want to run this locally so I was hoping to run it on pythonanywhere.

Question: If I have login and password info in plain text, is that safe to upload the file to pythonanywhere?

Also, does anyone have some resources on how I would go about setting up PythonAnywhere if it is a valid option

Comment: Also, if my bot is a Jupyter file do I need to have the upgraded subscription in order to run it?

Comment: `If I have login and password info in plain text, is that safe to upload the file to ...` <- No matter how that sentence ends, the answer will be no

Comment: Please limit your question to a single specific question, not multiple questions in one. Also do not add additional info as a comment, use the [edit] button to edit your question

Comment: To nuance @FlyingTeller's answer to your OP question -- it's basically as safe as your account is.